# Jquery Data table, sorting Table that comes from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Ok I am using jQuery data table to sort my tables, there's a page in which table comes as a response from Ajax request but I use document ready function for the table's id to make it sortable. What will be the solution here?

Code:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var target=$("#forum"); 
    $("#ct").change(function(){ 
        var val=$(this).val(); 
        if(val=="") { 
          } 
        else { 
          $.post('gt.php',{id:val},function(data){ target.html(data); }) 
          } 
     }); 
});
```

Comment: You need to post code that you have tried?

Comment: Ok So here is the code that gets the table from ajax response on Select Change event.
 <script>
   $("document").ready(function(){
    var target=$("#forum");
    $("#ct").change(function(){
     var val=$(this).val();
     
           if(val=="")
      {
   
   }
   else
   {
        $.post('gt.php',{id:val},function(data){
      target.html(data);
     
      })
   }
     });
    })
   </script>
Now I want to sort this new table using jquery datatable, what should be done here to bind the functionality of datatables to this table?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvr4xsuk/ isn't gonna work all that easily unless your `gt.php` returns a properly formatted `thead` and `tbody`. You'd perhaps be best off initialising the table and then using Datatables built in ajax to get the result from your PHP.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you, I fixed it, the problem was that I was closing the tbody tag inside loop :\.